# Comma separator in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Is there any way we can give comma separator formatting to numbers in WordPress
eg: 3,000 instead of 3000 or 100,000 instead of 100000.

Answer (score 1):

Using the php function will "hardcode" the format for all users.

There is a specific wordpress function number_format_i18n which should convert integer number to format based on the current locale.

If you want it to happen automatically for your overall website (assuming the theme or plugn author has used the above function like a good boy/girl!, then you can either set the language (locale determined by language) in your config.php.  Define WP_LANG

or if for a plugin/theme,  set the local using set_locale

To set WP_LANG automatically  for different users browsing to your site, there is a plugin called ["in their language"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/in-their-language/)

Answer (score 0):

to format *(any)* number in PHP (not specifically to wordpress), you can use php's [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function.